# How to show that a differential equation has a periodic orbit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I've been learning differential equations, but I can't solve this exercise:

**Show that the following equation has a periodic orbit:**

$$u''-(1-u^2)u'+u^5 = 0$$

Can anyone show me how it is done?
I've tried to write it as a system

\begin{array}{lcl} x' & = & y \\ y' & = & (1-x^2)y-x^5 \end{array}

but every step i take past this point leads me to a dead end.

Comment: Apply [Lienard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lienard%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint.

Considering instead

$$
x^5 x' = x^5 y\\
y y' = y^2(1-x^2)-x^5 y
$$

and adding we have

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 16 x^6+\frac 12 y^2\right) = y^2(1-x^2)
$$

so we have that

$$
0 < |x| < 1\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 16 x^6+\frac 12 y^2\right) > 0\\
|x| > 1 \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac 16 x^6+\frac 12 y^2\right) < 0
$$

Comment: I understand what you did when you expressed df/dt, but I can't see how you reached your final conclusions. I mean, why df/dt is greater than 0 when x is, let's say, 0.5?

Comment: Oh! I got it! because of the right hand sign! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Does this establish periodicity and time period? Is there a criterion?

Comment: Please, correct me if I'm wrong, but by the hints given by Cesareo you can see that as t goes to infinity with 0 < x < 1 the function will increase and it will decrease if x > 1. f(x,y) for 0 < x < 1 will never be greater than f(x, y) for x > 1, and vice-versa. So you can see that there is an orbit that is been approached by both sides depending on the initial value of x. So when t goes to infinity, both functions (the one with x0 in (0; 1) and the other with x0 > 1) will be in the same orbit.

Comment: Any periodic orbit around the origin has to cross regions with $|x|<1$. One needs some argument that the expansion in those patches does not undo the contraction in the segments with $|x|>1$.

Comment: Are you talking about the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem that states the any limited semi-orbit with an omega-limit without a singularity, must have omega-limit as a closed orbit? (I'm sorry about the phrasing, English isn't my native language)

Comment: I don't think this by itself proves there is a closed orbit. For instance, why can't the trajectories be unstable spirals crossing the lines $x = \pm 1$?